# Marginal Distribution using GARCH model: How to do inverse probability transform?

Tags: time-series, garch, copula, asset-returns, joint-probability

I have $n$ return series. I fitted AR(1)-GARCH(1,1) to each return series. Then used **probability integral transform**, PIT(residuals), to transform the residuals to have a uniform distribution. Then I fitted an $n$-dimensional copula to the data. I simulated 1000 points from the copula. Now, how can I transform these simulated points in [0,1], marginal $u$, back using the [inverse probability transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling) (inverse of marginal fitted by AR-GARCH), $F^{-1}(u)$.